# Pasar instancia de un formulario padre a un formulario hijo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Para poder invocar funciones desde un formulario2, que se encuentran en un formulario1, entiendo que es necesario que al llamar al formulario2 desde el formulario1, se indique la instancia del 1, para así poder usar sus funciones.

```
//Método para abrir formularios dentro del panel contenedor.
    public void AbrirFormulario<MiForm>() where MiForm : Form, new()
    {
        Form formulario;
        formulario = PanelContenedor.Controls.OfType<MiForm>().FirstOrDefault(); //Busca en la colección el formulario
        //Si el formulario/instancia no existe
        if (formulario == null)
        {
            formulario = new MiForm();
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            formulario.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
            PanelContenedor.Tag = formulario;                
            formulario.Show();
            formulario.BringToFront();
            formulario.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(CerrarFormulario);
        }
        else //Si el formulario/instancia existe
        {
            formulario.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

¿En que parte de esta función podría indicar al formulario que vaya a abrir, la instancia del formulario padre para poder así generar una relación?

Comment: cuando lo creas?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta @gbianchi

Comment: en cualquier parte le podes pasar una referencia al otro formulario.. cual es el problema que tuviste pasando la misma?

Comment: Que vengo de vb, y ahi no se manejan esas cosas, basta con algo como: PRINCIPAL.abrirformularui, y listo, le dices de que formulario lo tome y funciona perfecto. Aquí no, aunque no muestra ningun error, simplemente no hace nada.

Comment: venis de vb6 querras decir? igual en vb6 tenias que tener un puntero al formulario. Aca es lo mismo... Los formularios son clases como cualquier otra. Si queres llamar a un metodo de un formulario, necesitas guardar el formulario que creaste en una variable...